# Decomposing difference in outcomes between two groups

Tags: group-differences

I have a simple problem, but haven't found a solution yet.

Let $Y_{i}=\sum_{a} X^{a}_{i}*\omega^{a}_{i}$, where $Y$ is something I calculate, and everything else is observed.

$\sum_{a} X^{a}_{i}=1$, as this is these are the fractions of a day's time spent in activity $a$.

$\omega^{a}_{i}\in[0,1]$, as this is the fraction of time spent in activity $a$ outside of the home.

$Y_{i}$ is therefore the share of the day spent outside.

I am interested in the difference in outcomes between two groups, $M$ and $F$.
In particular, I computed estimates for:

$\mathbb{E}[Y_{i}|i\in M]-\mathbb{E}[Y_{i}|i\in F]$

and I'd like to produce a summary measure that captures how much of this difference is due to the groups having different distributions of $X$'s and how much is due to them having different distributions of $\omega$'s (something like "x% of the difference is due to differences in ...").

I'm happy to do this manually, via simulations or regressions - as long as the output is straightforward to explain and interpret.

Any suggestions or references?

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear that such an assignment of differences to $X$ and $\omega$ is even possible or uniquely defined.  Could you provide a small example of what you mean?

Comment: I agree, I'm stuck because I don't think the comparison is uniquely defined.
My first attempt was to take the F group and compute $E[Y_{i}|F]$ by drawing fictional $X$'s from the distribution of group M - that is, what if F and M drew from the same distribution of X?
I then repeated the same exercise computing the average in group F by drawing fictional $\omega$'s from the distribution of $\omega$'s in group M.
Of course, the differences I get from these two counterfactuals don't add up to the empirical difference between the two groups (and I understand why)

Comment: I asked for the example because I can't figure out what you're asking. You seem to agree that you're not even sure what you're asking!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. What's I'm looking for is something close to the Blinder–Oaxaca decomposition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinder%E2%80%93Oaxaca_decomposition). The problem with the latter is that it is not uniquely defined. Which is where I'm at. I was hoping there would be an alternative.